# Dropzone.js / C# web service. Uploading gives The HTTP verb POST used to access path

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, dropzone.js

I am trying to figure out how I get dropzone.js to work with a C# based web service. But the issue I got is that I am running into a 404 error after I selected a file to upload.

These are the steps I have done: In VS2012 I started an empty MVC4 application. Then I added and index.html, dropzone.js and jquery via NuGet (don't know if dropzone needs it, just added it to be save). Based on the example on the website of dropzone.js, I wrote the next html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="CSS/FileUploader.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/DropZone.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    <title>File Uploader test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/FileUpload/FileUploadController"
          class="dropzone" <!-- this css class contains: background-color: yellow; -->
          id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a routing to the routing config in the RouteConfig.cs like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FileUpload",
            url: "FileUpload/FileUploadController",
            defaults: new 
            { 
                controller = "FileUploadController", 
                action = "FileUpload" 
            }
        );
    }
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        return null; //Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the "return null" line just to test if the method is called properly. When I run the code and open the html page, the dropzone control works properly. But when I select a file, this error is shown: The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/FileUploadController/FileUpload' is not allowed. and I cannot figure out why. Also, the code doesnt break on the break point so I guess the method isn't called properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I can't help with C#. It seems as if everything with Dropzone is working fine. Just to make sure, you can set the `forceFallback` option on Dropzone so it will fallback to a normal file input element. This way you know that you are dealing with C# and HTML and no JS in between.

Comment: hey, thnx for answering. After searching what the 405 error actually means, I think it is a C# issue (or config file issue). I also tried it without JS (so just an html form with in it 2 input tags, one with type file and one with type submit). Form action is "/FileUploadController/FileUpload" and method is "post". But I get the same error so I don't think it is caused by dropzone.js itself.

Comment: I made one mistake I didnt see so far in the url part. I changed FileUploadController and FileUpload in the route config at the url property. Too bad it doesn't solve my problem, although I get a different error now: I get a 404 error instead of a 405.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what I am doing wrong. Although I needed an example to figure it out... Without it, I would never figure it out cause the solution didn't make sense in the first place. Let me share the solution, in case you didnt know it.

First of all I had my controller class looking like this (Maybe different names at some places)

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        return Json("All files have been successfully stored."); 
    }
}
```

and mapping to it like this

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Uploader", 
            "FileUploadController/UploadFiles/", 
            new { controller = "FileUploadController", action = "UploadFiles" } 
        );
```

In my first opinion, nothing wrong, all names matches and such. But, for reasons I don't know, when you try to call http://FileUploadController/UploadFiles/ the .NET code adds "Controller" to the Controller name part in the url. So, it tries to look for FileUploadControllerController. But I don't have that class so I get the error I mentioned in my previous post. As soon as I adapt my route mapping to

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Uploader", 
            "FileUpload/UploadFiles/", //not sure if removing Controller here is required
            new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "UploadFiles" } 
        );
```

the code works, UploadFiles is called and I get the Json string returned. To test my theory, I added Controller in both places (and in the html file as well of course) so, my class is named FileUploadControllerController and it works again.

I guess Microsoft tried us to force the right name convention, force us to add Controller at the end of a class name. Other reasons I cannot think of.

Comment: In fact the frameword don't add another "Controller" to your controller name, the framework remove it, because the sufix "Controler" is a reserved word. For example, if I have a controller "HomeController" I need to call him just by "Home".